# Web Console command not working

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, console

I am trying to use the web developer tool 'Web Console' along with 'Firebug'.  I am trying to simulate what happens when I click on this button by entering in a script to the webconsole but it isn't working.  Can someone help me figure out what to enter in the Web Console?  I asked my boss for help but he said this is the last straw!! Please help.

Here is the code with the button....

```
<div id="car_perf_internal" style="display: inline;">
  <span style="float:left;"> </span>
  <div class="select_box right nccDropToggleSection">
    <a id="Left" class="NCCPUSHBUTTON" href="javascript:;" onclick="iToggleDisplay(this, 'nccDropToggleSection', 'nccDropToggleContent', null, null, 2);">
  <span>
<input id="buttons_K_NC_TITLE" class="NCCPUSHBUTTON" type="button" value="Performance Documents" name="buttons_K_NC_TITLE">
</span>
</a>
```

I tried entering this into the web console, but it said 'TypeError: a is undefined'

```
iToggleDisplay('Left', 'nccDropToggleSection', 'nccDropToggleContent', null, null, 2);
```

Comment: You're passing a string to the function `'Left'` instead of the element node `document.getElementById('Left')`. Quite what's causing that particular error message I don't know, but I imagine it'd help if you pass the right arguments to the function.

Answer (score 2):

`Left` isn't a dom element, it's the ID value. You need to convert it to an element:

```
iToggleDisplay(document.getElementById('Left'), 'nccDropToggleSection', 'nccDropToggleContent', null, null, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, that seems to be close, but now it is returning 'false', do you have any ideas why this may be??

Comment: you'll just steal it and use it for yourself!  Ive had ppl do that and Ive got burnt!!

Comment: @FirstLast - your function is returning false. If you don't show it, we can't help. Edit your question, add the function.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to pass the reference to the element, not just an id.

```
iToggleDisplay(document.getElementById('Left'), 'nccDropToggleSection', 'nccDropToggleContent', null, null, 2);
```

other option is to call click

```
var elem = document.getElementById("Left");
elem.onclick.apply(elem);
```

Comment: Thanks Epscarello, that seems to be close, but now it is returning 'false', do you have any ideas why this may be??

Comment: returning false? what are you talking about? Is that what the function is returning and the console is reporting that?

Answer (score 0):

If you place some code in html in event attribute, then `this` points to the dom object (in your case to the link with id `Left`). To get this you may get it by id with `document.getElementById` function:

```
iToggleDisplay(document.getElementById('Left'), 'nccDropToggleSection', 'nccDropToggleContent', null, null, 2);
```

But you can emulate button click this way:

```
document.getElementById('Left').click();
```

Comment: Thanks Spartacus, that seems to be close, but now it is returning 'false', do you have any ideas why this may be??

Comment: It should go to a different page because it is a link

Comment: let me try that...also when I tried this... iToggleDisplay(document.getElementById('car_perf_internal'), 'nccDropToggleSection', 'nccDropToggleContent', null, null, 2);  it returned 'true'...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16367/discussion-between-first-last-and-speransky-danil)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the actual `DOM` node and not the `id` as the first parameter

So instead of

```
iToggleDisplay('Left', 'nccDropToggleSection', 'nccDropToggleContent', null, null, 2);
```

it should be

```
iToggleDisplay(document.getElementById('Left'), 'nccDropToggleSection', 'nccDropToggleContent', null, null, 2);
```

Because `this` refers to the node itself